# MacOS, c++ python extension cannot find a dynamic library

Tags: python, c++, macos, cmake

I'm building a c++ python extension. So far, I created versions for Linux and Windows. Currently, I'm struggling with the MacOS version. CMake produces 2 libraries:

```
  43898860 Aug 29 13:40 libslide_io.dylib
    214876 Aug 29 13:40 slideio.cpython-35m-darwin.so
```

I pack them to a whl file. After installation with pip, when I try to import the package, I'm getting the following error:

```
(sld-35)dist % python -c "import slideio"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/envs/sld-35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/slideio.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libslide_io.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/.../opt/anaconda3/envs/sld-35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/slideio.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Both libraries are correctly placed to the python environment directory:

```
/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/envs/sld-35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
```

Moreover, if I unzip the whl file and import the package from the current directory, it works.

I suspect that it is something with rpath settings in my cmake files, but cannot find the correct solution. All my attempts are failed.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is interested. I solved the problem by adding a  post-build with the execution of ***install_name*** utility with the *@loader_path* parameter. The command instructs the system looking for the library at the loader (in my case - the python package) folder.

```
if (APPLE)
   add_custom_command(TARGET ${BINDLIB_NAME}
           POST_BUILD COMMAND
           ${CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL} -change libslide_io.dylib @loader_path/libslide_io.dylib
           $<TARGET_FILE:${BINDLIB_NAME}>)
endif()
```